# Hadoop Rest API for upload / download

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

I am trying to perform upload/download a file from Hadoop cluster, using a C# app, but  I couldn't find the APIs for Upload and download from the documentation.

So can you please let me know how to upload and download files from Hadoop using RestAPIs?

Thanks

Comment: Download is Open/Read and Upload is Create/Write/Append, it uses file system terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WebHDFS REST API as described here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html

**Edit:**

Create and Write to a File

**Step 1:**

Submit a HTTP PUT request without automatically following redirects and without sending the file data.

> curl -i -X PUT "http://:/webhdfs/v1/?op=CREATE
>                       [&overwrite=][&blocksize=][&replication=]
>                       [&permission=][&buffersize=]"

The request is redirected to a datanode where the file data is to be written:
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Location: http://:/webhdfs/v1/?op=CREATE...
Content-Length: 0

**Step 2:**

Submit another HTTP PUT request using the URL in the Location header with the file data to be written.

> curl -i -X PUT -T 
>   "http://:/webhdfs/v1/?op=CREATE..."

The client receives a 201 Created response with zero content length and the WebHDFS URI of the file in the Location header:
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: webhdfs://:/
Content-Length: 0

Note that the reason of having two-step create/append is for preventing clients to send out data before the redirect. This issue is addressed by the "Expect: 100-continue" header in HTTP/1.1; see RFC 2616, Section 8.2.3. Unfortunately, there are software library bugs (e.g. Jetty 6 HTTP server and Java 6 HTTP client), which do not correctly implement "Expect: 100-continue". The two-step create/append is a temporary workaround for the software library bugs.

Comment: I did referred the documentation, but I couldn't find any APIs for file upload and download.

Comment: Thanks. So for uploading I have to create a new file and write the contents of the uploaded file to it. Right? So what about download? Is there any way ? Currently I'm using shell commands in a 'cmd' process to download a file.

Comment: Yes you can use a get request
[curl -i -L "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=OPEN"]