# Add file to HDFS from Hadoop Web UI

Tags: user-interface, hadoop, web, hdfs

Is there any way to add files inside the HDFS using the Web UI.

On http://localhost:50070/ or at some else url .
Does something like that exists?

Comment: Which web ui? Is that the namenode ui that you're referring to?

Comment: There is an API, not exactly an interface without some other installed components. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993421/hadoop-rest-api-for-upload-download

Answer (score 1):

No. The web interface doesn't have a feature to add files.

But you may check-out [HUE](http://gethue.com) or [Ambari with Files View](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-commandline-manage-files-hdfs/#section_2).

Comment: What about WebHDFS? Or Ambari?

Comment: The WebHDFS REST API may be used to add files: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE

Comment: Yeah, Ambari added a Files view. It's included in the HDP stack, not sure about a plain Hadoop install.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes files view may be used to modify file (that is if Files View is enabled on Ambari).

Comment: It can upload as well, last time I checked

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it can, but that is only if `Files View` is also installed.